# running anacron as non root issue

Tags: linux, cron

I was tring to run anacron as non root. But my RHEL doens't have -S option on anacron.
Since the default spool directory for anacron is /var/spool/anacron, does it mean as a non root user, I can't run anacron since I don't have write permissions to it? Thanks,

Here is the man page for anarcon on my RHEL.

NAME
       anacron - runs commands periodically

SYNOPSIS
       anacron [-s] [-f] [-n] [-d] [-q] [-t anacrontab] [job] ...
       anacron -u [-t anacrontab] [job] ...
       anacron [-V|-h]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want anacron to run as a non-privileged user, you'll need to use an existing user or create an anacron user and set the anacron spool to this non-privileged user.

```
# useradd anacron
# groupadd anacron
# chown root.anacron /var/spool/anacron
# chmod g+w /var/spool/anacron
```